# Regex python and html : looking for dots outside markups?

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I have been testing and looking in books and forums for hours without finding the answer, so here is the tricky question.

I am parsing an html file and BeautifulSoup gives me a txt and html versions of a text.

Now I want to split the text in sentences (according to [?!. ]* as end of sentence), so I have :

```
sentences_txt   = re.compile("[^?!.]+?[?!. ]*").findall(txt) # this work : return a list of sentences
```

and I want to make a list of the same number sentences but for their html counter part, like :

```
sentences_html  = re.compile("[^?!.]+?[?!. ]*").findall(html) # this doesn't work
```

It doesn't work because when there are markups, it will split in the middle of the markup as soon as it find one of the character [?!.].

**==> How can I split an html text according to [?!.] when they are not inside a markup ?**

I tried some things using (?

```
sentences_html  = re.compile("(?:<.*>)*[^?!.]+?[?!. ]*").findall(html) # doesn't work 

sentences_html  = re.compile("(?<!<)[^?!.]+?(?!>)[?!. ]*").findall(html) # doesn't work
```

Comment: Required don't use regex comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @user3318273 Could you give an example string and the output you're looking for please?

Comment: @JakobBowyer: That's my Pavlov reaction to the tag cobmination of [tag:html] and [tag:regex], but OP is doing the parsing with [tag:beautifulsoup].

Comment: @user3318273 do you expect the members of `sentences_html` to be well-formed HTML? Do you expect `sentences_html[0]` to contain the `<head>`?